# Linux Mint SPDIF Out Not Working

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I'm running Linux Mint 15 (Cinnamon) on a computer with a GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3 motherboard. The only issue that I have had is the sound. The analog outs work fine, but I cannot get any sound from the optical out. I have tried several fixes that I have seen, including editing the `alsa-base` modprobe file. Here is the output from `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `alsa-tools` installed? I ahd a similar issue and installing them solved it. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools
```

Comment: You might want to expand this into slightly more information, this is really a comment rather than an answer.